# Kafka : Use common consumer group to access multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Our cluster runs Kafka 0.11 and has strict restrictions on using consumer groups. We cannot use arbitrary consumer groups so Admin has to create required consumer groups.

We run Kafka Connect HDFS Sinks to read data from topics and write to HDFS. All the topics have only one partition.

I can consider following two patterns when using Consumer Groups in Kafka HDFS Sink.

As shown in the pictures:

Case 1: Each topic has its own Consumer Group
[image]

Case 2: All the topics have a common Consumer Group
[image]

I am aware that when a topic has multiple partitions, and if a consumer failed, another consumer in the same consumer group take over that partition.

My question :

Does the same thing happen when multiple topics share the same consumer group? ie: if a Consumer failed(HDFS Sink), will another Consumer(HDFS Sink connector) takeover the work and read from that topic?

**Update**: Each Kafka HDFS Sink Connector subscribed to only one topic.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I'm surprised that all answers with "yes" are wrong. I just tested it and having the same `group.id` for consumers for *different* topic works well and does NOT mean that they share messages, because for Kafka the key is `(topic, group)` rather than just `(group)`. Here is what I did:

1. created 2 different topics T1 and T2 with 2 partitions in each topic
2. created 2 consumers with the same group `xxx`
3. assigned consumer C1 to T1, consumer C2 to T2
4. produced messages to T1 - only consumer C1 assigned to T1 processed them
5. produced messages to T2 - only consumer C2 assigned to T2 processed them
6. killed consumer C1 and repeated 4-5 steps. Only consumer C2 processed messages from T2
7. messages from T1 were not processed

Conclusion: Consumers with the same group name subscribed to *different* topics will NOT consume messages from other topics, because the key is `(topic, group)`

Comment: yes ,this is the correct behavior i expected. I think others assumed that my consumers subscribe to both T1 and T2 .

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya feel free to accept the correct answer then

Comment: @borN_free i dont think anyone claimed they would see records from topics they dont own. to complete your experiment, try and force a rebalance by adding partitions to one of the topics and you will see ALL consumers (even those that dont care about that topic) stop to rebalance.

Comment: In Step 1, if you create T1 with only ONE partition, T2 still two, what would happen? When starting Kafka, C2 complains about having not enough partition, even though T2 is enough. Have you seen that?

Comment: @borN_free Could you please share a code example how you have done it?

Comment: @borN_free I think the question is what happens if consumer C1 and C2 each subscribe to both topics. I think in such case if you kill C1, C2 will read from both topics

Comment: I think consuming different topics with same consumer group id works just fine, but over a period of time it is causing **Broker: Group rebalance in progress** error.

Comment: I encountered the following problem: two consumers are subscribed to different topics and belong to the same group, the number of messages in the topics is different. The second consumer does not receive a message from his topic. If you make different groups for them, then everything is ok. It feels like an offset from the first consumer is applied to the second consumer (since they are in the same group) and he no longer sees his messages. Can anyone double check this?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely yes. The kafka consumers should monitor both topics and then, kafka will assign the partitions (per topic) to the current active members of the consumer group.

Regardless of having one or multiple partitions on every single topic, the consumers will take charge of monitoring the partitions per topic whenever a consumer failure happens in the same group.
When a failure happens, the Kafka will always trigger the **re-balancing** process in order to distribute the partitions to the remaining active consumers of the group and as a consequence, the work will continue running on that topics.

Comment: my question is not regarding rebalamcing partitions..its about whether rebalacing happens for different topics in a same consumer group

Comment: the answer is yes. if the consumers were registered/subscribed on both topics then they will start getting messages from the other topic when one consumer fails.

Comment: @Alexadreison If the hdfs sinks are different then whats the point of writing the data, read from different topics into different sinks.

Answer (score 0):

yes, as long as both consumers subscribe() the the same set of topics (topicA and topicB) the partitions of all topics will be distributed across all consumers.

in your case this would mean that if one of the consumers fails, both topics will be assigned to the surviving consumer.

Comment: In Kafka Connect, each Consumer subscribe to only one specific topic. This case, there wont be any rebalance right?

Comment: i dont use kafka connect, so i cant answer that

Answer (score -1):

The question asked is **in the event of consumer fails in a consumer group, will the consumers available in the same group pick up the subscribed topics and starts processing again or not?**.

But the accepted answer has the scenario where the topics are assigned to consumers, but if its auto assignment(i.e., subscribe) then the consumers that are idle in the group should pick the job of failed consumer and starts reading from the last committed offset. If its not then its breaking the consumer group parallelism architecture.

just look at this answer. [Kafka consumer for multiple topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568947/kafka-consumer-for-multiple-topic)

Comment: I think you are confusing topics with partitions in your answer